# How to get data from a SQLBinary object

Tags: c#

I'm receiving a SQLBinary object. I want to get the data inside it. I know it is the result of a Select statement.

how can I read the records?, so I can manipulate them

Related to the SqlBinary.Value property, I tried Convert.ToBase64String , System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString to get some readable information (maybe an XML) but without success.

Thank you.

Comment: [SqlBinary.Value Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlbinary.value(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The `SqlBinary.Value` property is a `byte[]` with length specified in `SqlBinary.Length`

You can read more by clicking on the properties in [the documentation for `SqlBinary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlbinary(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately, the documetation says nothing about how to manipulate the information contained in that byte array, it just gives you the byte array.

Comment: It's not going to tell you what to do with it. You need to know what's in it to know what to do, just like with any other byte array. What are you expecting it to contain? an image? xml text? plain text?

Answer (score 0):

System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString worked!. It seems it was only an encoding issue!